# How to select all columns from table A IF column name is specified in another table TSQL

Tags: sql-server

I have table B which will have Rows of ParameterCode and Value.

I have table A which will have columns of different Variables.

I want to match the column name of A with the value of ParameterCode in B.

If B.ParameterCode(row) matches a column name in A (in this case origin) I want to return it.

Basically, how do I look up and match column names from row values?

I am certain i am just forgetting something very simple.

Table B Example:

```
DECLARE @B TABLE(ParameterCode VARCHAR(64), Value varchar(64))

INSERT @B VALUES ('Origin','SLC')
```

Table A Example

```
    DECLARE @A TABLE(
Origin varchar(100),
Destination VARCHAR(100),
Passengers int
)
insert into @A values
('SLC','JFK','1')
```

And only origin would be selected.

Result

```
   DECLARE @Result TABLE(
Origin varchar(100),

)
insert into @Result values
('SLC')
```

Comment: your description and the table name in example does not match at all. Please change

Comment: basically you use `INNER JOIN` to find matching rows of two tables. Or `EXISTS` to find a rows that exists in another table

Comment: My problem is I am wanting to match the column name of one table with the row value of another.

Comment: please also include expected result. Also you might want to change the sample data. Looking at it looks like a `INNER JOIN` as both table contains the row with value `origin`

Comment: Still unclear, why `SLC`? What's the relevance of `AHO`?

Comment: [1]  Does your Table B only contains one row ? [2] What is the input to the query ?

Comment: Sorry changed the AHO.

Comment: Not sure what you mean for [2]....for this example yes only one row. Basically if the ParameterCode from B matches any variable name in A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unpivot your table `@A` first, and then do a `JOIN` on `@B`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/6954/0)

```
;WITH CteValues AS(
    SELECT x.* , a.Passengers
    FROM @A a
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES
        ('Origin', Origin),
        ('Destination', Destination)
    )x(ParameterCode, ParameterValue)
)
SELECT cv.ParameterValue, cv.Passengers
FROM CteValues cv
INNER JOIN @B b
    ON b.ParameterCode = cv.ParameterCode
    AND b.Value = cv.ParameterValue
```